# Implement new slider in Android 13 media player via Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-you

Is there a way to set the stroke of Bezier curves in Android canvas? And also how do I animate the shift of slider track. [Image of the desired slider.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqv0w.png)

I opened the Material 3 slider implementation in Jetpack Compose. And there you can change the slider track with any other Compose function. The shift of the Bezier curve along the Y axis did not give the desired result. And the mathematical shift of the curve along the normal is too complicated an operation for a small interface element. I think there is a much simpler way to implement such a slider.

Comment: https://github.com/galaxygoldfish/waveslider

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77927207/8583692) and [this library](https://GitHub.com/mahozad/wavy-slider)